# Mongoose find which part of $or was triggered

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I don't know how to state this question. But I have some similar to this code:

```
User.findOne({$or:[ {'local.email':email}, 
                    {'local.name': req.body.name} ]}, function(err, existingUser) {
```

Is there a way to know if a user was found by email or by name? Because I need to tell users in the registration form that either username or email is already taken. Or should I do 2 queries for such a task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, just check the `existingUser` document you get back to see which matched:

```
User.findOne({$or:[ {'local.email':email}, 
                    {'local.name': req.body.name} ]}, function(err, existingUser) 
{
    if (existingUser) {
        if (existingUser.local.email == email) {
            // email matched
        }
        else {
            // name matched
        }
    }
```

Comment: that was what I was about top post :p You beat me by 30 secs -:)

Comment: Of course I had it sitting there for a couple hours thinking...someone else will probably answer this...before I just went ahead and answered ;-)

Comment: Hahaha.  that was a nice one :p